# Update Object properties from Object Repository

Tags: qtp

I have developed QTP script for a application in descriptive programming approch. I have used functions to reuse the code(Functions are in .vbs file). I will add objects to object repository and change the script such the object will be identified from OR. Now my question is, do the objects in .vbs file will get automatically update if i make changes for the objects in object repository.

Thanks In advance:)

Comment: Change the object how? Are you going to change the logical names too or just the properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same name as in Repository, like this

```
Window(“Notepad”).WinEditor(“Edit”).Type “yes”
```

Then it will work fine, as it will use it from Object Repository. And if you update any object properties, then it will work fine. But if you update object name\parent name, then it won't found it.

Scripts in vbs file use object repository from Action that calls that script. So, if you use the same vbs script in different Actions, then you need to use Shared Object Repository, so you vbs scripts will found these objects